# django specifying multiple labels

Tags: python, django, label, modelform

By default, when a form is created in django using ModelForm, the labels for each field are basically the name of each field with the first letter capitalized. However, I want to write my own labels for each of the fields instead of using the default ones. Is there a shortcut for doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, add [verbose_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/models/#verbose-field-names) to the field definition.